# Return immediately from `call(env)` after providing a response

Tags: ruby

I have a Rack web server app to validate in `call(env)` the provided HTTP query string and return different responses immediately (with appropriate erb) if those bits of validations fail.

I'm calling the following method to provide a response:

```
def respond(http_status, http_headers, html_body = '')
  # Provide HTTP response
  html_body = yield if block_given?
  [http_status, http_headers, [html_body]]
end
```

which I gleaned from the web.

I'm then calling `respond(...)` from different points inside my `call(env)` method rather like this:

```
def call(env)
  case blah
    when '/'
      if validation_a_fails
        respond(invalid_a)
      else
        set up a variable for later use...
      end
      if validation_b_fails
        respond(invalid_b)
      else
        set up another variable for later use...
      end
      if validation_c_fails
        respond(invalid_c)
      else
        set up something else for later use...
      end
    else # not root url
      respond(404_situation)
    end
  end
end
```

I expected that a call to `respond(invalid_a)` would exit the call method immediately. However, it doesn't. Instead, the rest of the call method are executed.

How can I get the `respond(...)` to return immediately to the calling browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if validation_a_fails
  return respond(invalid_a)
else
```

in your case you can't omit `return` because you have multiple `if-else`s so it'd go through them.

Comment: Hey, my pleasure :)